# function not executed when creating objects in a loop - javascript

Tags: javascript, function

In the following code the drawFunc is not executed during the loop (I can see that with a step-by-step-debugging, the code just jumps to the end of the function).

The function gets executed at the line "stage.add(layer);", causing a bug.

Any help on how to fix this?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            canvas {
                border: 1px solid #9C9898;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v3.9.7.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {

                // global parameters
                var curvatureX = 10;
                var curvatureY = 10;
                var nodeRadius = 10;

                var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                    container: "container",
                    width: 578,
                    height: 300
                });
                var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();


                var nodes = [];

                for (var i = 0;i<10;i++){
                    nodes[i] = new Kinetic.Circle({
                        x: i*20,
                        y: i*5,
                        z:1,
                        radius: nodeRadius,
                        fill: "blue",
                        stroke: "black",
                        strokeWidth: 4
                    });
                    layer.add(nodes[i]);


                }


                var edges = [];
                for (var i = 0;i<9;i++){
                    console.log("just after the for: "+i);
                    edges[i]= new Kinetic.Shape({


// *** PROBLEMS IS HERE
// *** FOR LOOP SKIPS THE FOLLOWING LINES

                        drawFunc: function() {
                            var context = this.getContext();
                            context.beginPath();
                            console.log("in the drawing function: "+i);
                            context.moveTo(nodes[i].getX(), nodes[i].getY());
                            if ((nodes[i].getY()-nodes[i+1].getY())<0){
                                context.quadraticCurveTo((nodes[i].getX()+nodes[i+1].getX()+curvatureX)/2, (nodes[i].getY()+nodes[i+1].getY()-curvatureY)/2, nodes[i+1].getX(), nodes[i+1].getY());
                            }
                            else{
                                context.quadraticCurveTo((nodes[i].getX()+nodes[i+1].getX()+curvatureX)/2, (nodes[i].getY()+nodes[i+1].getY()+curvatureY)/2, nodes[i+1].getX(), nodes[i+1].getY());

                            }
                            context.lineWidth = 10;
                            // line color
                            context.strokeStyle = "black";
                            context.stroke();
                        },

// *** LOOP RESUMES HERE


                        fill: "#00D2FF",
                        stroke: "black",
                        strokeWidth: 4
                    });
                    layer.add(edges[i]);
                }


                //*** FUNCTION IS EXECUTED HERE, CAUSING BUG.
                stage.add(layer);

                var amplitude_1 = 100;
                var amplitude_2 = 30;
                var period = 2000;
                // in ms
                var centerX = stage.getWidth() / 2;
                var centerY = stage.getHeight() / 2;

                stage.onFrame(function(frame) {
                    for (var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
                        nodes[i].setX(amplitude_1 * i * Math.sin(frame.time * 2 * Math.PI / period) + centerX);
                        nodes[i].setY(amplitude_2 * i+ 20);
                    }
                    layer.draw();

                });

                stage.start();
            };

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're defining a function as part of an object, not calling it explicitly, AFAICT, so there's no reason it would execute in the loop--so the framework is calling it. Which means something in the framework isn't happy about your draw function. I'd be a little nervous about the "this" reference because of JS's "this" semantics, if that isn't the issue, then it's something else framework-specific. You don't include any error info, so can't help there.

Comment: yes, when arrived at "stage.add(layer);" an error "nodes[i + 1] is undefined".This is thrown because at this moment  the indice i has a value of 9. Trying to execute the function throws an error because it tries to fetch nodes[i+1], which is nodes[10] => does not exist.

Comment: Then your draw function needs to enclose the loops "i" value, there are a number of ways to do this, including building the function instead of simply defining it.

Comment: ok, I don't know how to do that... ?

Comment: Search SO or google for javascript function closure or javascript loop value closure etc, it's a very common problem. Also, if you don't use a @ tag with a username, like @seinecle, ppl may never know that you've replied to them.

Comment: We need some sort of FAQ for this - I can't remember how many times I've answered this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** use a variable declared *outside* a function and assume that its value when used *inside* that function is what it was at the time the function was declared.

In the particular case of a loop variable, that variable will have the *last* value assigned to it by the time the inner function is called.

To fix this, you have to "close" the outer variable's value inside a new scope, in your case that would look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    ...
    drawFunc: (function(i) {  //  <------------+
        return function() {   //               |
            alert(i);         // you can use this "i" here
        }
    })(i)
}
```

The unusual looking construct now there is an *immediately invoked function expression* which has been *passed* your loop variable `i`, but now has a locally bound copy of that variable in its scope.

Comment: thx @Alnitak this is very clear. Just: why the last (i) bit at the end?

Comment: @seinecle because that's how the current value of the "outer" `i` is passed to the IIFE.

Comment: @Altinak great I learned a lot + I got the code to work. Thanks a lot.