# onresize doesn't seem to work when in a loop (javascript)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, onresize

I'm trying to call a function based on screen size inside a loop'.

The function works fine when the page is loaded, however, the content doesn't change when the window is resized.

Here's an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/celine305/BaNRq/27/

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  function red() {
    $('#' + i + '').css('background', '#B60C0C')
      .text('Screen Size RED');
  }

  function orange() {
    $('#' + i + '').css('background', '#EBAE10')
      .text('Screen Size ORANGE');
  }

  function green() {
    $('#' + i + '').css('background', '#83ba2b')
      .text('Screen Size GREEN');
  }

  var widths = [0, 500, 850];

  function resizeFn() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= widths[0] && window.innerWidth < widths[1]) {
      red();
    } else if (window.innerWidth >= widths[1] && window.innerWidth < widths[2]) {
      orange();
    } else {
      green();
    }
  }
  resizeFn();
  window.onresize = resizeFn();
}
```

Comment: why is java tagged?

Comment: I don't see the point of the for loop, it's just wasted computation.

Comment: Try defining your functions outside the loop, and then calling them with parameters for the i'th iteration of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move your functions outside of the `for` loop
2. Merge 3 functions to one
3. Use a jQuery listener instead of JavaScript since you're using jQuery already

---

```
// You could also assign classes and use $(".className") instead of loop
function changeColor(color) {
    for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
        $('#'+i+'').css('background',color).text('Screen Size' + color);
    }
}

var widths = [0, 500, 850];

function resizeFn() {
    if (window.innerWidth>=widths[0] &&window.innerWidth<widths[1]) {
        changeColor('#B60C0C');
    } else if (window.innerWidth>=widths[1] && window.innerWidth<widths[2]) {
        changeColor('#EBAE10');
    } else {
        changeColor('#83ba2b');
    }
}

resizeFn();
$(window).resize(function() {
    console.log("resize");
    resizeFn();
})
```

**JSFiddle renders the content inside a `div` so your code was never detecting the resize. I added a container to detect the resize, but otherwise you should use `$(window)`.**

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BaNRq/29/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the current code, you will likely have to move the function declarations outside of the for loop. [See this article.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696015/javascript-creating-functions-in-a-for-loop)

As a side note though, I would recommend moving away from javascript for handeling these style changes. CSS offers a good way to handle style changes for predetermined sizes in the form of [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of your loop seems to be selecting the elements. You can do this much simpler by selecting all your elements with one query:

```
$("#1, #2")
```

Because you're doing EVERYTHING in the loop, you are redefining functions and are assigning the resize-function multiple times.

Oh, and by the way, you are not really assigning a function to the window.onresize event handler, but the return value of a function. Try assigning it without the trailing braces.

Comment: @spencerWieczorek  this is just a simple version of a much larger code (with around 50 elements).

Comment: In this case, give all elements a common class and select them by the class. If that is not possible for you, create a selector string in a loop and pass that string to jQuery.