# Iterating with callback/anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, schedule, iife

I'm new to Node.JS and advanced Javascript in general, but I'm trying to build a schedule manager application on my own and I faced a problem (I will detail it later) when trying to execute the following code:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
var day = new Date(req.query.day);
Location.getLocations(function (err, locations) {
    if (locations.length > 0) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var location = locations[i];
            Appointment.getAppointments(day, location, function (err, appointments) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (appointments.length == 0) {
                    // CREATE APPOINTMENTS
                    for (var j = location.available_time_start; j <= location.available_time_end; j += location.appointment_duration) {
                        var newAppointment = new Appointment();

                        newAppointment.start_date = new Date(day.getFullYear(), day.getMonth() + 1, day.getDate(), j);
                        newAppointment.appointment_duration = location.appointment_duration;
                        newAppointment.location = location.id;
                        newAppointment.booked = false;
                        newAppointment.locked = false;

                        Appointment.createAppointment(newAppointment, function (err, appointment) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            console.log(appointment.location + ' - ' + appointment.start_date);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        // THERE ARE NO LOCATIONS
    }

    res.render('appointments', { locations: locations });
});
```

The problem is:
When I try to iterate the `locations` object and then execute the `getAppointments` function the code isn't executed at this exact moment. Later, when it's executed, `location` object is always the same (the iteration doesn't work), resulting on a unexpected result (all appointments with the same/last location).

I tried using IIFE (Immediately-invoked function expression) to execute the code instantly, but when I did this I couldn't get the `appointments` callback object and my logic is broken too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19696026/5203655) for more info on callbacks and loops

Comment: Actually I viewed this before, but it doesn't seems to apply to my case. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: use `let` instead of `var` will most likely fix your issues

Comment: Thanks, it works! Coincidentally I was reading about `let` on this post when you commented: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-let-and-const/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by using `let` instead of `var` as suggested by @JaromandaX.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be saving appointments but doesn't do anything with the saved appointments (are you mutating locations?).

When saving an appointment goes wrong the requestor doesn't know about it because `createAppointment` is asynchronous and by the time the callback is called back `res.render('appointments', { locations: locations });` is already executed.

You could try converting your callback based functions to promises:

```
const asPromise = (fn,...args) =>
  new Promise(
    (resolve,reject)=>
      fn.apply(undefined,
        args.concat(//assuming one value to resole
          (err,result)=>(err)?reject(err):resolve(result)
        )
      )
  );
const savedAppointmentsForLocation = (day,location,appointments) => {
  const savedAppointments = [];
  if (appointments.length == 0) {
    // CREATE APPOINTMENTS
    for (var j = location.available_time_start; j <= location.available_time_end; j += location.appointment_duration) {
      var newAppointment = new Appointment();
      newAppointment.start_date = new Date(day.getFullYear(), day.getMonth() + 1, day.getDate(), j);
      newAppointment.appointment_duration = location.appointment_duration;
      newAppointment.location = location.id;
      newAppointment.booked = false;
      newAppointment.locked = false;
      savedAppointments.push(
        asPromise(
          Appointment.createAppointment.bind(Appointment),
          newAppointment
        )
      );
    }
  }
  //you are not doing anything with the result of the saved appointment
  //  I'll save it as promise to see if something went wrong to indicate
  //  to the requestor of the api that something went wrong
  return Promise.all(savedAppointments);
}

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var day = new Date(req.query.day);
  asPromise(Location.getLocations.bind(Location))
  .then(
    locations=>
      promise.all(
        locations.map(
          location=>
            asPromise(Appointment.getAppointments.bind(Appointment),[day,location])
            .then(appointments=>[location,appointments])
        )
      )
  )
  .then(
    results=>//results should be [ [location,[appointment,appointment]],...]
      Promise.all(
        results.map(
          ([location,appointments])=>
            savedAppointmentsForLocation(day,location,appointments)
            .then(ignoredSavedAppointment=>location)
        )
      )
  )
  .then(locations=>res.render('appointments', { locations: locations }))
  .catch(
    error=>{
      console.log("something went wrong:",error);
      res.status(500).send("Error in code");
    }
  )
});
```

Comment: After your comment I studied a lot about promises and refactored my code to use them. Now I have a lot more control with the solution. Thanks!