# JavaScript ES6 tax calculations with some items being exempt

Tags: javascript, oop, object, ecmascript-6

I am setting up a es6/oop tax calculator and having some issues setting the tax amount correctly. I am instantiating product objects with their quantity and price and adding them to an inventory and then calling a total method on the entire inventory. Some products are tax exempt, so I am using a BasicProduct object and an ExemptProduct object:

```
const Product = require('./Product')

class ExemptProduct extends Product {
  constructor(product) {
    super(product)

    this._salesTax = product.salesTax
  }

  get salesTax() {
    return this.setSalesTax();
  }

  setSalesTax () {
    return null;
  }
}

module.exports = ExemptProduct
```

The BasicObject sets the sales tax to .10. My `total` method is here:

```
total() {
    let total = 0
    let tax = 0
    let importDuty = .05

    for (let productId in this.items) {
        total += this.inventory.products.find(product => {
            return product.id == productId
        }).price * this.items[productId]

        tax += this.inventory.products.find(product => {
            return product.id == productId
        }).salesTax * this.items[productId]

        console.log(tax)
    }

    let taxToApply = total * tax
    let importDutyToApply = total * importDuty
    total = total + taxToApply + importDutyToApply

    return total
}
```

Right now I am testing with three inventory items, two of which are instantiating as tax exempt products. They all log out with the correct tax amount until they hit this `for in`. The console.log I left in there is printing out .10 for all three, when two of them should be 0/null. I am trying to avoid hard coding the tax amount per item, as ultimately there will only be two tax types.

Comment: I think you've run into a common JavaScript gotcha: function closures in for-loops do not work as you expect them to. Take a look at this related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696015/javascript-creating-functions-in-a-for-loop

Comment: @PatrickHund That has nothing to do with it. Not only is `find` synchronous, the code also uses `let` syntax.

Comment: `0` is not the same as `null`. Use the number when you are dealing with numbers.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `instance.salesTax` to return? Is it a percentage, is the tax for that item? Why do you in your loop both accumulate `tax` (with `+=`) on all items, *and* then also multiply (`*`) it with the `total`?

Comment: You are right @Bergi I was jumping to quick conclusions

Comment: The salesTax is the percentage. Only some items are exempt, so 0 would be hard to work with, as I'd be multiplying a total by 0, which would return 0. That's another can of worms I guess. The tax is the actual tax amount, before being added to the total. I need to print that out in a receipt. So I need to break it down like such: Price: 10.00, Tax: 1, Total: 11.

Comment: Not sure the best practice to not apply tax for the exempt items, but multiplying by null does indeed return 0.

Comment: > The console.log I left in there is printing out .10 for all three, when two of them should be 0/null. < You're not logging the tax of each item individually. You're logging the accumulated tax. Notice that you += each item's individual tax to your variable tax. .1 + 0 is still .1.